# initialising references during declaration

Tags: c++, c

Why is it required to initialise the references during its initialisation. If not initialised it throws errors. Is it const datas should always be initialised with a value. Why is it only with constants and does not require a variable to be initialised during declaration.

EDITED:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=10,b=12;
    int &c=a;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    c=b;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

This is a c program where I used reference. Am I wrong in this?

Comment: Could you clarify? You are talking about references, but you have tagged the question as C language question.

Comment: But we can use references in c also.Is reference in cand c++ differs.If so please explain me.I'm unaware of this.

Comment: References do not exist in C. And by references throwing errors you mean something like `int& k;` right? EDIT: That is your problem, it needs to be compiled as C++ to work since references do not exist in C.

Comment: @Joe:what do we call &c in c .. Does it refers to address and not a reference.My understanding about reference is that "any variable preceded by an &" which is a const pointer and is an alias name for a variable.Please help me understand! EDIT:I compiled in visual studio-2008

Comment: @Angus: In C++, `int &c = a;` *declares* `c` as a reference to `d`.  However, in something like `int *p = &a;`, the `&` means "take the address of".  In C, only the second use is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted can't be compiled as a C program, since there are no references in C.

To make it compile as C, you would have to modify it:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=10,b=12;
    int *c=&a;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    *c=b;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("%d\n",*c);
    return 0;
}
```

As for C++ references, the fact that a reference needs to be initialized is one of the major differences between pointers and references.

Pointers can be NULL or invalid, references can't (actually, you can generate an invalid reference, but the compiler should warn you about that). In a way, a reference works as an alias. By writing `int a; int &b=a;`, you now have two names for one variable (or memory location).

Answer (score 2):

In C there are no references. You probably mean address operator:
[http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Faddre.htm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/addre.htm)

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way it is. There are pointers which don't have to be initialized and may be later assigned to. References can be thought of as synonyms of objects - you can't have a synonym of nothing.

In general, you have to initialize anything which you can't later assign to - e.g. constants and references. If you were allowed ***not*** to initialize them, then you should be allowed to assign to them a new value later which ruins the whole purpose